# Is this "as" a relative pronoun?

Tags: relative-pronouns

> The caged eagle, whose gold-ringed eyes cruelty has extinguished,
>   might look **as** looked that sightless Samson. (Jane Eyre)

Is *as* a relative pronoun that has *the caged eagle* as its antecedent?
(It seems as-clause is a complement in the whole sentence, and it is also a subject in its clause. So it could be said a nominal relative clause. This idea seems plausible, yet I can’t find the use of as.)

Comment: What made you think it is a pronoun, of whatever kind? How is the research going so far? Can you share your findings?

Comment: @Kris I added what I so far have found and imagined.

Comment: That portion of the sentence can be rephrased as "might look like that sightless Samson looked." *As* functions in the same manner as *like* here.

Comment: @onomatomaniak Isn't *like* one of the synonyms of *as*? Why does it even need to 'function like' *like*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. **as** in this case is a conjunction. From Wikitonary, one of the definitions of **as** is the following, which matches your use:

> **as** *Conjunction* (dated)
>
> Introducing a comparison with a hypothetical state (+ subjunctive); ‘as though’, ‘as if’. [to 19th century]
>
> *1526, William Tyndale, trans. Bible, Acts II:*
>
> - And sodenly there cam a sounde from heven **as** it had bene the commynge off a myghty wynde* [...].
>
> *c. 1616, William Shakespeare, King Henry VI part 2, First Folio 1623, I.1:*
>
> *Oft haue I seene the haughty Cardinall, / More like a Souldier then a man o'th' Church, / As stout and proud **as** he were Lord of all* [...].

This is one of the problems of reading very old texts - you will have to deal with the fact that dated English sometimes has slightly different usage and/or grammar to modern English.

Comment: It's not Old English, it's Modern English, but it is dated. Shakespeare counts as [(early) Modern English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Modern_English).

Comment: @MattЭллен: I meant to say "old English" in the layman sense that it is English which is old. Shakespeare may be "Modern English" in the technical sense, but 1616 texts are not modern. I mean, for heaven's sake - that's like, *pre-Internet*, or something. People back then had to text each other with a pen and mail the text to each other. That's not modern. :)

Comment: @Matt +1 Great observation! 'not modern': like, pre-Internet. With you on that one.

Comment: @Matt They didn't even *mail* it. They had to hire a courier.